# MySQL syntax error 1064 near IN stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax, memsql, singlestore

an aspiring DBA Here.

I'm trying to create a stored procedure for a query I'm running. It is a memsql server which is MySQL based. The procedure is as such:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE calc_campaign (IN usr VARCHAR(38))
BEGIN

Awesome SELECT statement that uses a variable

END //
```

The error description is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'IN usr VARCHAR(38)) BEGIN my_statement; END' 
at line 1
```

The syntax I used seems to correspond with this:
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html
 And with pretty much every other procedure I saw on Stack forums.

What is it I'm missing here? Thanks for any help!

Comment: 1) The template is syntactically correct... maybe it is memsql server singularity? Try to remove `IN` at all. 2) If procedure body contains one single SELECT query, you do not need in BEGIN..END block and DELIMITER commands.

Comment: @Akina You were right. It's with memsql - nothing to do with the MySQL syntax. See the answer below.

Comment: Added [memsql] tag.  (But I don't know how to define it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MemSQL is not MySQL - see e.g. their page [MySQL Features Unsupported in MemSQL](https://docs.memsql.com/concepts/v6.7/mysql-features-unsupported-in-memsql/). For details on their stored procedure implementation, please refer to [MemSQL's documentation on stored procedures](https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.7/create-procedure/):

```
[USING database_name] CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE procedure_name ( [parameter_list] )
  [RETURNS { data_type [data_type_modifier] } ] AS
  [DECLARE variable_list] [ ...n ]
  BEGIN
    procedure_body
  END ;

parameter_list:
  parameter_name data_type [data_type_modifier [ ...n ] ] [, ...]

data_type_modifier:
  DEFAULT default_value | NOT NULL | NULL | COLLATE collation_name

variable_list:
  variable_name type_expression [= value_expression ] ; [... ;]
```

As you can see, there is apparently no support for declaring parameters as `IN`, `OUT`, or `INOUT`. (They do however support default values for parameters, something which neither MySQL nor MariaDB support!)